# uploade node js project get error 503 || cors / header error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

[image]i am trying to upload my project (only the server side) the client side is running localy
the project has been upload to heroku site
but i get error that i cant fix them
i using react,node js , express ,mongo DB

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const setServerConfiguration = (app) => {
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(cors());
};


const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserRoute = require("./routes/User.route");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/bank");
const setServerConfiguration = require("./config");
setServerConfiguration(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.use("/bank", (req,res)=>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://nodejs-bank.herokuapp.com/bank"); 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
},UserRoute);

app.listen(port);



  const baseUrl = "https://nodejs-bank.herokuapp.com/bank";

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const fetchUsers = () => {
    axios.get(baseUrl).then((response) => {
      setUsers(response.data);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey get a package called cors in your express application and put it at the top of you application

```
yarn add cors
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: hey 
i was doing it before 
before i upload this project to heroku 
i was using localy the front and back 
and i it worked because i was using the cors packgae
but even after i upload the backend project to heroku it not working and give me this error

Comment: How did you build your front end

Comment: can you be more specific? 
i using react and axios for the fetch data
i cant upload the code on the comment
so i upload my code to "sandbox"
and you can watch it 
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-rain-ziq94o